# Find two unknown coefficients of a polynomial given information about points and gradients of its graph

Tags: calculus

I've just started calculus last week. So far we've covered quotient, product, power and chain rule but I can't solve the following question:

> Find an expression for the gradient of the curve $y=x^3+px^2+2x+q$ where $p$ and $q$ are constants.

I could do this but got stuck at the next part

> Given that the tangents at $A= (O,q)$ and $B= (2,5)$ are parallel. Find the value of $p$ and $q$.

Comment: tangent lines are parallel means gradient is the same

Comment: @vasya i know that but i can't solve it for some reason.

Comment: The tangents are parallel if they have the same slope. The slope of the tangent is the same as the gradient of the curve. So use (i) your formula for the gradient, *and* (ii) the knowledge that if you plug in $x=2$ you will get $y=5$..

Comment: The fact that $B$ is on the graph tells you that $5 = (2)^3 + p(2)^2 + 2(2) + q = 4p+q+12$. That gives you one equation involving $p$ and $q$. Your formula for the gradient will give you another equality involving $p$ and $q$ (when you plug in $x=0$ you should get the same as when you plug in $x=2$). That will give you two equations in $p$ and $q$. Two equations in two unknowns;  solve them.

Comment: @arturo It turns out to y-5=(14+4p)(x-2) which is just 0=(14+4p)0. Am I supposed to do something else?

Comment: I'm sorry, but that looks like nonsense to me. Why are you taking $y-5$? Why are you equating that to $(14+4p)(x-2)$? Why does that matter? The **gradient** is a *number*, not an equation. The information doesn't say they are the same line.

Comment: @HamzaSadiq: you have a formula for gradient, right? Now plug in $x=0$ into that formula then plug in $x=2$ into the same formula and equal the results. You should be able to find $p$